# A property of hat functions

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Consider an interval $I$, subdivided into $t_0,t_1,...,t_N$ equispaced points. Consider the hat functions $v_i$ that are  piecewise linear, continuous  and such that $v_i(t_j)=\delta_{ij}$.

For which $f$ is it true that:
$$a_{i,j}=\int_0^T \left (\int_0^t f(s)v_i(s)ds\right )v_j(T-t)dt$$

is symmetric in $i,j$?

Not all $f$ work. Take $f=v_i$, and $j$ the opposite index to $i$, i.e. $j=N-i$. We assume that the grid is fine enough to have $|j-i|>1$.

Then, because the grid is equispaced, $v_j(T-t)=v_i(t)$ and we can see that $a_{i,j}$ is non null. On the other hand, $f$ and $v_j$ have disjoint support, so that $a_{j,i}=0$.